# How to capture the file upload, import timing and database performance testing in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing, database-testing

I am trying to achieve two scenarios using JMeter. But I am facing some issues. Details are as follows.
Scenario 1 : I want to test the timings of text file upload and file import in my web application
Scenario 2 : Need to verify the database performance. Here I am using MySQL database (SQL Workbench)

**Issues :
How to capture the time taken by the application for file upload and data importing in my web application**
**The structure of test plan for scenario 1**

[image]

**Issues :
After adding the .jar for driver its still giving an error as

Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver'

On selecting another driver class it is not returning anything in report.**
**The structure of test plan for scenario 2.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong driver:

- Your [JDBC URL](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-url-format) and your question assumes [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)
- Your [JDBC Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is for [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)

So you need to:

1. Download [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
3. Change your JDBC Driver Class to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`
4. Change "Validation Query" to `select 1`
5. Add an appropriate [Select statement](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_select.asp) checking the file import progress

See [How to Test MySQL Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-test-connection) article for more information if needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks set up is working but I want to test the time taken by the data of my imported file to get into database ?